# How to have more than 5 JUnits configurations saved in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

When I run a test in Junit it will automatically add it self to the run/Debug configuration.

That's great but since there a maximum 5 Unit tests there is removes other tests that I configured.

Is there a way to configure this number[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these are saved, they are greyed out.  If you want to takes them press the [disk] button (the forth from the left) once you do this, the save button should be greyed out instead.

You are limited to 5 unsaved (recent) configurations.

Comment: The terminology got me all mixed up.